# Amazon SES Sendmail - Is there a way to by pass or avoid receiver email verification process

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, email-verification, amazon-ses

I am using AWS EC2 instance to run web application and my web application required to send mail using gmail account to others. There is no problem on my development server to send mail through my apps. But after switched to EC2, I been forced to use AWS SES to sent email. It's not a problem to use SES but the problem is falled on email verification part. SES expect receiver emails to be verified as well before it's allowed to sent mail to the email address. To verify sender not a problem. We can just verify the sender. But the receiver part is the problem. The apps will get the request and sent out an email to the email address that's entered in the apps. We does not expect to verify all the receivers email address before we can sent out the mail. So this had caused the problem on my apps. Just to know how can I or is there anyway to by pass receiver(s) email verification on SES?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kind of accounts in SES: sandbox and production. In case of sandbox, you need to verify both (sender's and receiver's email id). In your case, you just need to switch from sandbox environment to production. Then, you don't need to verify the receiver's email address. To switch to production, raise the ticket with AWS to increase the SES sending limit.

Comment: Thanks submitted request will update when got the reply from Amazon.